# How to connect the kinetic sensor to my ROS computer

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So i finally finish building up my robot, with a litle computer built in into it.. And i just purchased a Kinetic sensor but the connector wont fit on one of the USB ports, so im guessing ill need to purchase one of those adapters than convert that kinetic port into USB and power ([http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Kinect-Hyperkin-AC-Adapter/dp/B0057K045O/ref=sr_1_4?rps=1&ie=UTF8&qid=1356728403&sr=8-4&keywords=Xbox+360+Kinect+AC+Adapter%2F+Power+Supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0057K045O))

Do i need to use that power cable? or the USB cable is good enough, also is the kinetic sensor i got the right one? or they actually sell one that comes already with USB port??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51181/how-to-connect-the-kinetic-sensor-to-my-ros-computer/) by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on 2012-12-28**:
how is the ASUS Xtion PRO LIVE compared with the kinetc???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes. you need the adapter shown in your mentioned link. and that adapter is enough. you don't need to buy other things.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on 2012-12-28**:
but do i have to use the power cable? If so i guess i have to cut the transformer it self and hook it to my robot battery...

**Comment by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) on 2012-12-29**:
I recall there's a way of connecting a kinect to a Create robot's power supply. If you find a tutorial on how to do that it might be a starting point to use your bot's battery.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-14**:
You will have to cut the cable.  The USB port is not enough.